# Selected Item of Autocomplete Textview Show as simple Textview?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, autocompletetextview, onitemclicklistener

I am using an Autocomplete Textview which shows some names from database.I want to show a name in a textview which I selected from autocomplete textview.Here is my code:

```
ArrayList<String> s1 = new ArrayList<String>();

      for (StudentInfo cn : studentInfo) {
            s1.add(cn.getName());
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,s1); 
       a1.setThreshold(1); 
        a1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

---

```
a1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
    }
        });
```

Comment: what is a1 in your code and you want to shot selected item in textview or in edittext???

Comment: a1 is the autocomplete textview and I want to show selected item in textview.

Comment: in autocomplete textview when you selct item it automatically set in autocomplete textview. no need impliment extra method for that. check here: http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2013/04/android-autocompletetextview-inside.html

Answer (score 31):

Try it this way:

```
AutoCompleteTextView a1 = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(...);

StudentInfo[] s1 = studentInfo.toArray(new StudentInfo[studentInfo.size()]);

ArrayAdapter<StudentInfo> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<StudentInfo>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, s1);
a1.setAdapter(adapter);
a1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
        Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        if (item instanceof StudentInfo){
        StudentInfo student=(StudentInfo) item;
            doSomethingWith(student);
        }
    }
});
```

The ArrayAdapter uses the toString() method of StudentInfo to generate the displayed texts, so you need to implement a nice toString method.

This way, this kind of implementation can be adapted to any object type.

Btw.: i prefer **android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item** instead of **android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line**

Comment: Its not showing the drop down, could u help me out.

Comment: parent.getItemAtPosition(position); its giving position of list shown, so position did not match with original data, its not giving desired output

Comment: @Shivang is right. The real solution here: https://spapas.github.io/2019/04/05/android-custom-filter-adapter/. You need to expose the FilterResult values.

Comment: No, `parent.getItemAtPosition(position)` works well for filtered lists. I checked that.

Comment: How android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item does differ from android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line?

Comment: I have two autocomplete input box, If I choose the id, then automatically the value for that id needs to be set in the next autocomplete input box. {response: [{id: '', value: ''}, i{d: '', value: ''}}]}

Answer (score 11):

Gratitude to Stefan Richter! I would like to add that it is possible to use `List<T>` directly when you construct the adapter:

```
AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.autoComplete);
            // Where mStudentsInfo is List<StudentInfo>
            ArrayAdapter<StudentInfo> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, mStudentsInfo);
            autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
            autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    if (item instanceof StudentInfo) {
                        StudentInfo studentInfo = (StudentInfo) item;
                        // do something with the studentInfo object
                    }
                }
            });
```

And also do not forget to override the `toString()` method in `StudentInfo.class`:

```
public class StudentInfo {

....

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return studentName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can `item instanceof StudentInfo` be false? `ArrayAdapter<StudentInfo>` sets all items as `StudentInfo`.

Comment: @CoolMind, I always check before cast. Always! :)

Comment: A believe you, but what is a condition to get `item` not an instance of `StudentInfo`?

Answer (score 4):

overriding `toString` method for model class (StudenInfo in this case) is not a good idea!
If you only want to get the text of selected item, use this code:

```
 autoCompleteView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String selectedItem = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                // here is your selected item
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

your `s1` contains all the names from `database`

```
a1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                    long arg3) {
            Log.d("your selected item",""+s1.get(position));
            //s1.get(position) is name selected from autocompletetextview
            // now you can show the value on textview. 
    }
        });
```

hope this will helps you,

Comment: NB! In this example position argument is not the position inside s1, it is index to whatever the autocomplete happened to show at the time of selection.

Answer (score 3):

From the view object **arg1** get the value of the String. From the ArrayList supplied to the AutoCompleteTextView get the position of the item using this String.

in your case the code would look something like below.

```
int selectedPos = s1.indexOf((String) ((TextView) arg1).getText());
```

`selectedPos` is the position of the string in the supplied ArrayList.

Answer (score 2):

To get selected item from autocomplete selection which uses user defined datatype and sets values of related list.following code worked for me

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
long arg3) {
    int selectedPos = getYourList().indexOf((((TextView)view).getText()).toString());
    SomeDAO dao = getSomeDaoList().get(selectedPos);
    //do your code
}
```

Note: I have changed default parameter names in onItemClick as arg0-parent, arg1-view,arg2-position & SomeDAO is user-defined datatype

Answer (score 1):

Use parent position is '0'

```
  txt_search.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int position, long id) {
            Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(0);
            if (item instanceof MYData{
                MYData data=(MYData) item;
                String dd = data.getName();
            }
        }
    });
```